# AdxStudio: How display an entity form in Web template(Liquid Templates)

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals

I am trying to display an [entity form](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/entity-form/) in a adxStudio [web template](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/liquid-templates/basics/web-template/), found one link [Using Liquid to display EntityForm](https://community.adxstudio.com/forums/adxstudio-portals/62de1633-b751-e511-80dc-000d3a10150a)

```
<div class="container">{% entityform name:'My Entity Form' %}</div>
```

but this did't work for me.

Please help me to put an entity form on web template in adxstudio.

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved It!**

Initially I am trying to display the web template with footer web template of home page, which did't work.

For displaying Entity form We need to:

1. Place the **Entity Form** in **Web template** like `<div class="container">{% entityform name:'My Entity Form' %}</div>`
2. Associate the **Web template** to a **Page template**
3. Page template needs to associate to a **Web page**
4. Browse the page, finally you will see/submit your form.

Thanks!